# how handle different type in column with dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table like below,

```
+----------+-----+
|       tmp|index|
+----------+-----+
| [user1,0]|    0|
| [user1,3]|    1|
|[user1,15]|    2|
```

I want split tmp column to tow columns. tmp is String type, index is Int.

I write the udf as below.

```
val getUser_id = udf( ( s : (String, Int)) => {
  s._1
})
newSession.withColumn( "user_id", getUser_id($"tmp"))
```

The result is:

> Failed to execute user defined function(anonfun$4: (struct<_1:string,_2:int>) => string)

Would you like help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Row` not `Tuple`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val getUser_id = udf( ( s: Row) => {
  s.getString(0)
})
```

or

```
val getUser_id = udf( ( s: Row) => {
 val Row(id: String, _) = s
 id
})
```

but here you should `select`:

```
newSession.withColumn( "user_id", getUser_id($"tmp._1"))
```